# Combine Tkirnet modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have created a code to make a menu bar containing a menu bar with File, Edit and About menubuttons with a drop buttons.

I want to make separate modules for File,Edit and About buttons as file.py edit.py and about.py and then import them in a single file and run how to make such modules.

```
    from Tkinter import *
    def donothing():
       filewin = Toplevel(root)
       button = Button(filewin, text="Do nothing button")
       button.pack()

    root = Tk()
    menubar = Menu(root)
    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
    editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Setting", command=donothing)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
    aboutmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    aboutmenu.add_command(label="Help", command=donothing)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="About", menu=aboutmenu)
    root.config(menu=menubar)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question in your question. What do you need help with? Have you actually tried to put code in separate files and import them? If not, what is stopping you?

Comment: I would imagine you would use a class in a separate python module and import that class into your code and call what you need out of the class.

Comment: You could do what I did and put everything into a function. I just call the function any time i need to update my menu as I have menu items that can be added by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could do this using functions. Keep in mind ever function could be moved to another python module and then you could import the function.

```
from tkinter import *

def donothing():
    pass

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)
def fileMenu():
    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

def editMenu():
    editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Setting", command=donothing)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)

def aboutMenu():
    aboutmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    aboutmenu.add_command(label="Help", command=donothing)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="About", menu=aboutmenu)

fileMenu()
editMenu()
aboutMenu()

root.mainloop()
```

If you had the functions on 3 separate module (file.py,edit.py,about.py) you could import them like this.

```
from tkinter import *
from file import fileMenu
from edit import editMenu
from about import aboutMenu
```

Keep in mind you may need to deal with some dependent variables in your separate files. Note the menubar = Menu(root) will be needed in all the files if you do it this way.

After some testing I was able to move all the functions to a separate module and import them but not without problems. I only imported functions to test this however I believe it would be best to put this all into a class and call each method in the class to create each menu item.